# Vuetify : Navbar open specific links in new tabs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a navbar component that looked sth like this.

[image]

There are 2 menu options that I need to open in a new tab.

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <v-app-bar text app color="blue">
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="white--text" @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-app-bar-title class="text-uppercase white--text">
                <!-- <span class="font-weight-light">Vi3</span>
                <span>Global</span> -->
            </v-app-bar-title>
        </v-app-bar>

        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="grey lighten-1">
            <v-list>
                <v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router :to="link.route">
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>

                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title> {{ link.text }} </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            drawer: true,
            links: [
                { icon: 'dashboard', text: 'Dashboard', route: '/dashboard', newTab: false },
                { icon: 'leaderboard', text: 'Stats', route: 'https://www.google.com ', newTab: true },
                { icon: 'qr_code_scanner', text: 'QR Codes', route: '/qr-codes', newTab: false },
                { icon: 'tungsten', text: 'Campaigns', route: '/Campaigns', newTab: false },
                { icon: 'link', text: 'URL Groups', route: '/url-groups', newTab: false },
                { icon: 'settings', text: 'Settings', route: '/settings', newTab: false },
                { icon: 'support', text: 'Support', route: 'https://youtube.com', newTab: true },
                { icon: 'exit_to_app', text: 'Logout', route: '/' }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        created() {
            if (this.link.text == 'Support') {
                console.log('Support')
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How do I add a logic and catch that?

I tried put the URL in it, it kept adding / in front of it which lead to this

[image]

Any hints for me ?

## I tried

```
<v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router :to="link.route" target="link.text == 'Support' ? '_blank' : '']">
```

It doesn’t look so cleaned, and the extra / still there.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of vuetify you are using, but in the documentation for v-list-item you've got 2 useful props :

- [href](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-href) -> Use your link.route variable here
- [target](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-target) -> You should try with the value "_blank" (this value mean to open the link in a new tab, in html - see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp))

About what you tried, change it to that :

```
<v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" :href="link.route" :target="link.newTab ? '_blank' : ''">
```

Comment: I use the `2.4.0`, it the only version that compatible for Vue2 right now.

Comment: This solution, somehow still prepend / to the beginning of the URL.

Comment: Your answer is not working.

Answer (score -2):

For greater cleaning in template I usually create a method in these cases. Then your `v-list-item` may be:

```
<v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" @click="go(link)">
```

And run with this method:

```
go(link){
    if(!link.newTab){ 
         this.$router.push({ path: link.route })
    }
    else{
         window.open(link.route)
    }
},
```

Comment: I like this clean solution, but it kept sending me to this `http://localhost:8080/https:/www.google.com` ....

Comment: It add `http://localhost:8080/` -- which I don't want.

Comment: I think this is related to configuration issues of your vue router. If you want we can deal with it in another question.

Comment: I asked a new question upon request. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70413536/vuetify-how-to-configure-vuerouter-to-open-link-on-a-new-tab

Comment: Your answer is not working.

Comment: Excuse me sir. It is working like a charm and you can test it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vuetify-v-list-item-with-links-ck5lpk?file=src/views/Home.vue

Comment: could you try the example?