# Vuetify : How to configure VueRouter to open link on a new tab?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a navbar with a menu that users can click on. Some links will need to open up a new tab. This is what I have and I couldn't get it to work.

```html
<template>
    <nav>
        <v-app-bar text app color="blue">
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="white--text" @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-app-bar-title class="text-uppercase white--text">
                <span class="font-weight-light">Logo</span>
                <span>Global</span>
            </v-app-bar-title>
        </v-app-bar>

        <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="grey lighten-1">
            <v-list>
                <img class="ml-5 mb-3" src="../assets/Logo-Blue.png" width="70" />

                <v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router :to="link.route" @click="go(link)">
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title> {{ link.text }} </v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            drawer: true,
            links: [
                { icon: 'home', text: 'Dashboard', route: '/dashboard', newTab: false },
                { icon: 'leaderboard', text: 'Stats', route: 'www.google.com ', newTab: true },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        go(link) {
            console.log('go run ...')
            console.log(link)
            console.log(process.env.APP_URL)

            if (!link.newTab) {
                this.$router.push({ path: link.route })
            } else {
                window.open(link.route)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

**src/router/index.js**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})

export default router
```

Did I do sth wrong ?

Open up a new tab seems to work, but it kept prepending my localhost URL.

Comment: With window.open your vue-router should not be used, therefore your base URL shouldn't be added. Have you simply try to refresh your browser cache after changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a `click`-handler with the `v-list-item`, since that defeats the underlying anchor tag generated for the routing, and has accessibility implications. Stick with the `v-list-item`'s props that are built in for routing:

- **`href`**: To create an external link with `<v-list-item>`, use the `href` prop. Internal links should use `to` instead.
- **`target`**: To open a new window upon clicking the link, use the `target="_blank"` prop.

A `v-list-item` that links to an external URL would use the `href` prop like this:

```html
<v-list-item href="https://google.com">Google</v-list-item>
```

And one that opens a new tab would use the `target="_blank"` prop:

```html
<v-list-item target="_blank" href="https://google.com">Google</v-list-item>
```

Internal links use the `to` prop instead of `href`:

```html
<v-list-item to="/dashboard">Dashboard</v-list-item>
```

And they could be opened in a new tab with `target="_blank"` as well:

```html
<v-list-item target="_blank" to="/dashboard">Dashboard</v-list-item>
```

#### Solution

In your case, you have an array of items that need to bind the previously mentioned props conditionally. That's best done using [`v-bind` with an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) (where the object's key-value pairs are bound as component props) that is computed based on each item's properties:

1. [Compute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) a new array of links (named `computedLinks`) that has a new prop to bind (named `linkProps`):

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    computedLinks() {
      return this.links.map(link => {
        const isExternalLink = url => /^((https?:)?\/\/)/.test(url)
        const linkProps = {
          [isExternalLink(link.route) ? 'href' : 'to']: link.route,
        }
        if (link.newTab) {
          linkProps.target = '_blank'
        }
        return {
          ...link,
          linkProps,
        }
      })
    },
  },
}
```

2. Update the template to use `computedLinks`, and bind each link's `linkProps` to its corresponding `v-list-item`:

```html
<v-list-item v-for="link in computedLinks" :key="link.text" v-bind="link.linkProps">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vuetify-v-list-item-with-links?file=src/views/Home.vue)